# Comparing 2 arrays and adding some text to the common element of the master array?

Tags: java

I have to compare a master array with a child array and tag the master array with a certain text (say "#") for the common ones -

```
MasterArray = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}
ChildArray = {"A", "C"}

OutputArray = {"A#", "B", "C#", "D", "E"}
```

The output will be displayed directly to `JList`. I am using it here to explain the requirement.

What should I use to get the same output...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your arrays to ArrayLists using [`Arrays.asList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) to make them easier to work with. Then iterate over your master array and check if the child array contains each element using the [`ArrayList.contains`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method. If it does, append '#' to the element. Here is some sample code to help you:

```
String[] master = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
String[] child = { "A", "C" };

//convert to lists
List<String> masterList = Arrays.asList(master);
List<String> childList = Arrays.asList(child);

//iterate over the master
for (int i = 0; i < masterList.size(); i++) {
    String m = masterList.get(i);

    //check child contains the master element
    if (childList.contains(m)) {
        //append #
        masterList.set(i, m + '#');
    }
}

//convert to array and create a jList
JList jlist = new JList(masterList.toArray());
```

Comment: @dogbane- Thanks a lot :). No need to convert the `ArrayList` to `List`. The code works for `ArrayLists`. So why convert them..?

Answer (score 0):

```
String Master[]={"a","b","c","d"};
        String Child[]={"a","c"};

        int mlength=Master.length;
        int clength=Child.length;

        String Result[]=new String[mlength];


        for(int i=0;i<mlength;i++)
        {Result[i]=Master[i];
            for(int j=0;j<clength;j++)
            {
                if(Master[i].equals(Child[j])){Result[i]=Master[i]+"#";break;}
            }
        }
        JList dataList = new JList(Result);

         for(int i = 0; i < dataList.getModel().getSize(); i++) {
             System.out.println(dataList.getModel().getElementAt(i));
         }
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Test this code:

```
        String[] MasterArray = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
        String[] ChildArray = {"A", "C"};

        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for(String s : ChildArray){
            map.put(s, s+"#");
        }

        List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String s : MasterArray){
            if(map.containsKey(s)){
                output.add(map.get(s));
            }else{
                output.add(s);
            }
        }
```

Then you get the result as a list if you want it as an array just convert it (toArray())

Answer (score 0):

consider also to use a lookup hash-like structure (for example HashSet). This is important 
if your arrays are big.
The provided solution have a O(n*m) complexity (compare all elements of the master array with all the elements of the child array). This can be reduced to O(nlogm). When using the lookup hash:
Basically:

```
Set lookup;

// O( n logn) complexity

for(Elem in MasterArray) {
    lookup.add(Elem);
}

// O(m) complexity
for(Elem in ChildArray) {
   if(lookup.contains(Elem) {
     // mark it with # whatever.
   }
}
```